# Shell script: Get name of last file in a folder by alphabetical order

Tags: shell

I have a folder with backups from a MySQL database that are created automatically. Their name consists of the date the backup was made, like so:

```
2010-06-12_19-45-05.mysql.gz  
2010-06-14_19-45-05.mysql.gz  
2010-06-18_19-45-05.mysql.gz  
2010-07-01_19-45-05.mysql.gz
```

What is a way to get the filename of the last file in the list, i.e. of the one which in alphabetical order comes last?

In a shell script, I would like to do something like

```
LAST_BACKUP_FILE= ???
gunzip $LAST_BACKUP_FILE;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ls -1 | tail -n 1
```

If you want to assign this to a variable, use `$(...)` or backticks.

```
FILE=`ls -1 | tail -n 1`
FILE=$(ls -1 | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: How would I limit the ls to .gz files only in a fixed path? (Like: The last file with the extension .gz in the folder /home/xy/abc)

Comment: Just like you use `ls` normally, something like `ls -1 /home/xy/abc/*.gz`.

Answer (score 10):

@Sjoerd's answer is correct, I'll just pick a few nits from it:

1. you don't need the `-1` option to enforce one path per line if you pipe the output somewhere:

   ```
   ls | tail -n 1
   ```
2. you can use `-r` to get the listing in reverse order, and take the first one:

   ```
   ls -r | head -n 1
   ```
3. `gunzip some.log.gz` will write uncompressed data into `some.log` and remove `some.log.gz`, which may or may not be what you want (probably isn't).  if you want to keep the compressed source, pipe it into `gunzip`:

   ```
   gunzip < some.file.gz
   ```
4. you might want to protect the script against situation when the dir contains no files, since

   ```
   gunzip $empty_variable
   ```

expands to just

```
    gunzip
```

and such invocation will wait indefinitely for data on standard input:

```
    latest="$(ls -r /some/where/*.gz | head -1)"
    if test -z "$latest"; then
      # there's no logs yet, bail out
      exit
    fi
    gunzip < $latest
```

Comment: (1) Yup; (2) Yup; (3) or '`gzip -cd some.file.gz >some.file`' leaves the original compressed file around; (4) Yup - check results before using them.

Answer (score 8):

`ls` can yield unexpected results when parsed by other commands if the filenames have unusual characters.  The following always works:

```
for LAST_BACKUP_FILE in *; do : ; done
```

`for LAST_BACKUP_FILE in *` loops through every filename (and folder name, if there are any) in order in the current directory, storing each in `$LAST_BACKUP_FILE`

`do :` does nothing

`done` finishes after the last file

Now, the last file is stored in `$LAST_BACKUP_FILE`.

If you happen to want the first file, use this:

```
for FIRST_BACKUP_FILE in *; do break; done
```

The `break` statement jumps out of the loop after the first file is stored in `$FIRST_BACKUPT_FILE`.

*(from comment below)* If you want hidden files included in the search, then use the command `shopt -s dotglob` before running the loops.

Comment: This is the only answer in this thread that is not suicidal. [You should never parse the output of `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: This doesn't work with hidden files in Bash, unless you `shopt -s dotglob` first.

Answer (score 2):

The shell is more powerful than many think. Just let it work for you. Assuming filenames without spaces,

```
set -- $(ls -r *.gz)
LAST_BACKUP_FILE=$1
```

does the trick with a single fork, no pipes, and you can even avoid the fork if your shell supports arithmetic expansion as in

```
set -- *.gz
shift $(($# - 1))
LAST_BACKUP_FILE=$1
```